# A question involving the module of differentials

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $B$ be a local ring. Let $k$ be its residue field. Do we need $B$ to contain a copy of $k$ in order for the following to be true:
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{k}({\Omega_{B/k}\otimes_{B} k},k)=\operatorname{Hom}_{B}(\Omega_{B/k},k)$$
as $k$-vector spaces, of course.

Thank you.

Comment: Presumably, $\otimes$ is $\otimes_B$?

Comment: If you denote by $M$ the $B$-module of differentials $\Omega_{B/k}$  then the canonical isomorphism is just the extension of scalars - restriction of scalars duo, so that would work for any $B$-module $M$. However, in order to have $\Omega_{B/k}$ you need a map $k \to B$.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful.